# Options for external monitor display

Tags: xubuntu, display, external-monitor

Every time I plug in an external monitor via hdmi, I get presented four options, of which the only 'extend' option is to extend the display to the right. The way my desk is set up, I need to extend the display to the left. I can open Display from the menu to change this, but this requires about four more clicks than desirable. Is there any way to change the defaults in the menu that comes up when you plug in an external monitor?

I am running Xubuntu 15.04.

Comment: which graphic driver that is running on the machine?

Comment: i believe it's intel integrated